# Defining a custom table for AuthComponent

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I've created a simple CMS to manage several small websites built on CakePHP. After successfully migrating the plugin from 1.3 to 2.0 I'm running into a problem with the AuthComponent after updating Cake to the latest version 2.1.2.

The classnames of the plugin are all prefixed by the plugin's name to avoid duplicate classnames, as the application shares most of its tables with the plugin. So there are cases when I have a `UsersController` for the main application and a `PluginNameUsersController` for my CMS plugin (or a `PostsController` and a `PluginNamePostsController`). The plugin models rely on `$useTable` to find the correct database table (so `PluginNamePostsController` still uses `posts`).

Since upgrading to the 2.1.* branch of Cake the `AuthComponent` has ceased to work as it expects a non-existent `pluginname_users` table instead of referring to `users`.

Is it possible to define a custom table for the `AuthComponent` or is there any other method to get this working? Also, is this behaviour expected?

The component is configured in `PluginNameAppController` as follows:

```
  public $components = array(
    'Session', 'RequestHandler',
    'Auth'=> array(
      'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'pluginname_users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => 'pluginname'
      ),
      'loginRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'pluginname_posts',
        'action' => 'index',
        'plugin' => 'pluginname'
      ),
      'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
          'userModel' => 'PluginNameUser',
          'fields' => array('username', 'password')
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AuthComponent is actually unaware of tables and such. By using a custom model, you can define `$table` on it to work on a different table. So, the first thing is to set up your plugin's model to use the proper table:

```
class PluginNameUser extends PluginAppModel {
  public $table = 'users';
}
```

Then, tell your authentication methods to use the plugin's model by using the dot syntax.

```
'authenticate' => array(
   'Form' => array(
     'userModel' => 'PluginName.PluginNameUser',
     'fields' => array('username', 'password')
   )
 )
```

Now when FormAuthenticate tries to authenticate, it will try and find the user using that model, which it now knows is in PluginName. It loads the model, which you've set to use the `users` table, and looks for the user there.

Comment: Actually, defining `$table` in the `PluginNameUser` model didn't seem to be necessary. I neglected to prefix the `userModel` with the name of the plugin, probably because I was staring myself blind at a bigger non-existent problem. After prefixing the `userModel` Auth starts to work again. Thanks for the help!